Combining multiple (more than 2) tables on multiple columns
I'm working with multiple tables in Postgres that look similar to this:
create table samples
(sampleid,Location,SampleDate)as values
 (1,    'A',    'Jan 1')
,(2,    'B',    'Mar 5')
,(3,    'A',    'Feb 17');

create table mature_organisms
(SampleID,SpeciesCode,Count)as values
 (1,    'x',    100)
,(1,    'y',    23)
,(1,    'z',    53);

create table juvenile_organisms
(SampleID,SpeciesCode,Count)as values
 (1,    'x',    20)
,(1,    'w',    15)
,(1,    'z',    5);

And so on for many samples.  Some species appear in both the mature and juvenile tables, some will appear in only one table depending on the sample.
What I want to output is a table that looks something like this:



SampleID
Location
SampleDate
species
mature_count
juvenile_count




1
A
Jan 1
w

15


1
A
Jan 1
x
100
20


1
A
Jan 1
y
23



1
A
Jan 1
z
53
5



Can this be done without ending up with duplicated columns?
The best I could do was
SELECT m.sampleid
     , j.sampleid
     , s.location
     , s.SampleDate
     , m.speciescode
     , j.speciescode
     , m.count as mcount
     , j.count as count
FROM samples s
RIGHT JOIN mature_organisms m 
  on s.sampleid=m.sampleid
FULL JOIN juvenile_organisms j 
  on m.sampleid=j.sampleid 
 AND m.speciescode=j.speciescode;

Which gives me two sampleid columns and two speciescode columns:



sampleid
sampleid
location
sampledate
speciescode
speciescode
mcount
count




null
1
null
null
null
w
null
15


1
1
A
Jan 1
x
x
100
20


1
null
A
Jan 1
y
null
23
null


1
1
A
Jan 1
z
z
53
5




"Which gives me two sampleid columns and two speciescode columns." - uh just remove them from your SELECT clause if you want only one of each? Your conditions already constrain both columns to have the same value anyway.

Why do you have spiecies in multiple tables? The only difference is their status, juvenile or mature. I would first change my data model.

@FrankHeikens, I wish I could combine the tables, but this is how the DB was built and I'm not allowed to change it.  Mine is not to reason why...

@Bergi, that doesn't work.  If I specify only sampleid or speciescode from only 1 table, I end up with blank values in that column if the specified table has no data but the other table does.  If I don't specify a table, Postgres complains about ambiguous references.


Can this be done without ending up with duplicated columns? If I specify only sampleid or speciescode from only 1 table, I end up with blank values in that column if the specified table has no data but the other table does.

For the sample id, you can just refer to s.sampleid from the samples table, not the organism tables which were joined against it.
For the species code, you can use the COALSCE function which ignores NULL values ("blanks") and can get you the value from either table.
Also you'll need to change the join order so that the samples table is joined last, against either the juvenile or mature organisms:

Parentheses can be used around JOIN clauses to control the join order. In the absence of parentheses, JOIN clauses nest left-to-right.

SELECT
  s.sampleid,
  s.location,
  s.date,
  COALESCE(m.speciescode, j.speciescode) AS species,
  m.count as "mature count",
  j.count as "juvenile count"
FROM samples s
JOIN (
  mature_organisms m
  FULL OUTER JOIN juvenile_organisms j ON m.sampleid=j.sampleid AND m.speciescode=j.speciescode
) ON s.sampleid=COALESCE(m.sampleid, j.sampleid);

Another approach is to use the USING clause for the join conditions, which gets rid of the duplicate columns automatically:
SELECT sampleid, location, speciescode AS species, m.count as "mature count", j.count as "juvenile count"
FROM samples JOIN (mature_organisms m FULL OUTER JOIN juvenile_organisms j USING (sampleid, speciescode)) USING (sampleid);


that almost works.  What it gives me is a table with a single column for species, but all the sample columns have blanks in the row where the juveniles-only species appears.

Ah I thought that was already working in your query. It seems like the JOIN order is wrong, you'll need to parenthesize the full outer join to happen before the right join.

Seems to work nicely.

@Bergi, yes, your second suggestion, with the USING clause and the parentheses did the trick!  Thank you!

@Bergi: I would put more focus on the superior solution with the USING clause.
